# Getting error when trying to run node.js with gRPC

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc

Before running my application I have successfully compiled protos but now I am getting this error. I would like to find out if problem is in built artefacts or missing node.js module. I am using docker with cubernetes.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984
throw err;
Error: Cannot find module '@myorganisation/protos/gl/metainfo/v1beta1/metainfo_pb'
Require stack:
/usr/src/node_modules/@myorganisation/grpc-header/lib/grpc-header.js
/usr/src/src/modules/grpc-header.module.js
/usr/src/src/modules/index.js
/usr/src/src/init.js
/usr/src/index.js
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:981:15)

code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [
     '/usr/src/node_modules/@myorganisation/grpc-header/lib/grpc-header.js',
      ......
]
```

Comment: I think you should show us your proto path structure

Comment: It looks like `grpc-header.js` is code you wrote. The error shows that it is trying to load a path that does not exist (the one that ends with `metainfo_pb`). So, why is it trying to load that path in particular, and where is your generated code getting output, if not there?